# How to edit an Item in a mutable list in f# and allow the other items in the list retain their values?

Tags: list, f#, mutable

I created a list in f# named tickets that contains 10 records called Ticket.The records are all initialized with their specific seat number and empty customer name.

```
type Ticket = {seat:int; customer:string}  
let mutable tickets = [for n in 1..10 -> {Ticket.seat = n; Ticket.customer = ""}]
```

I want to write a function to book a specific seat in the list(add a customer name to the seat).
How can i edit an item in the list and have other items still retain their value

Comment: What particular part are you stuck on?

Comment: @JohnPalmer I read somewhere that in f# i have to create a new list if i want to change an Item in the list.
This is what i came up with. But the new list now has only one Item.
let bookTicket()=
    Console.WriteLine("Enter seat number: ")
    let seatNo = int(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine("Enter customer name: ")
    let customerName = string(Console.ReadLine())
    tickets <- [{Ticket.seat = seatNo; Ticket.customer = customerName}]

Comment: @CharlesUko and this is true, in this case (if you really want to mutate things) I would just use `System.Collection.Generic.List<'t>` as you might be used to from C# - you can then get the old ticket with `let oldTicket = list.[itemNr]`, create a new record with `let newTicket = { oldTicket with customer = "newCustomerName" }` and put it back into the list with `list.[itemNr] <- newTicket`

Comment: maybe you even want to use an `Dictionary` (or you could try to work out the problem using F#'s `Map<'k,'v>`)

Comment: This is close to a duplicate of this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455367/is-replacing-a-list-element-an-anti-pattern

Comment: @JohnPalmer good point - I think a (functional) list is the wrong data-representation here anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functional F# list type is immutable, which means that you cannot change it. The typical way of working with it would be to return a new, modified, copy.

To do that, you can write a function `bookSeat` that takes `list<Ticket>` together with number & new name and produces a new `list<Ticket>` with that one field updated:

```
let bookSeat seatNo name tickets = 
  tickets |> List.map (fun ticket ->
    if ticket.seat = seatNo then { ticket with customer = name }
    else ticket )

bookSeat 3 "Tomas" tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use a list of mutable (ref-cells) tickets:

```
let maxSeats = 10
let tickets : (int * Ticket option) ref list =
    [1..maxSeats]
    |> List.map (fun s -> ref (s, None) )

let bookSeat seat name =
    match List.tryFind (fun r -> let (s,_) = !r in s = seat) tickets with
    | Some r -> 
        r :=
            match !r with
            | (s, Some ticket) -> (s, Some { ticket with customer = name })
            | (s, None)        -> (s, Some { seat = s; customer = name })
    | None ->
        failwith "seat not found"
```

obvious you can make `tickets` itself mutable too, if you want to `add` seats instead of initializing them with all the obvious seats

### a better approach(?)

Still I think that this is the wrong way to do it - I think you want a Map:

```
type Ticket = {seat:int; customer:string}  
type Tickets = Map<int, Ticket>

let bookSeat seat name (tickets : Tickets) =
    match Map.tryFind seat tickets with
    | Some oldTicket ->
        tickets 
        |> Map.remove seat
        |> Map.add seat { oldTicket with customer = name }
    | None ->
        tickets
        |> Map.add seat { seat = seat; customer = name }
```

note that these are all immutable values, so `bookSeat` will return a new `Ticket`-reservation-map

### hyprid using `Dictionary`

or you can use a common .net `Dictionary` and mutate this:

```
type Ticket = {seat:int; customer:string}  
let tickets = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, Ticket>()

let bookSeat seat name =
    match tickets.TryGetValue seat with
    | (true, oldTicket) ->
        tickets.[seat] <- { oldTicket with customer = name }
    | (false, _) ->
        tickets.[seat] <- { seat = seat; customer = name }
```

Here you don't have to pass the `Tickets` around - they will be mutated in place (but still the `Ticket`-objects themselves are still immutable)

Note that this right now is not thread-safe so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most idiomatic option here would be to simply use a `string array`. Given you know in advance the size and you want to be able to update it, this is the structure that fills both those needs most idiomatically.  So,

```
// create 10-element string array initialized with null
let (tickets : string array) = Array.zeroCreate 10 

...

tickets.[3] <- "New Customer"
```

keep it simple.

Granted this is not "purely-functional" (but any purely functional solutions here just kick the non-pure parts down the road anyway), but if the goal is just to get the job done, this will do it.